# Continuous Visual Studio errors on Debugging and Building project

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2022

This problem started a few days ago while I was working on my project. Up until then, I was not getting this error at all. Whenever I run "dotnet watch run" or launch the project from Visual Studio 2022's "Start Debugging" these errors will pop up, along with MSB3026 warnings, MSB3027 errors, MSB3061 errors. I also get CS0006 errors if I try to build or rebuild it.

These errors are also happening on other projects I create. If I make a simple console application and run, add new Console.WriteLine() and run/rebuild, eventually the errors will appear for that project too.

A common error message I get looks like "Error MSB3021 Unable to copy file "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\SocialHub\Persistence\bin\Debug\net8.0\Persistence.dll" to "bin\Debug\net8.0\Persistence.dll". The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open."

I've tried to fix these errors by:

- Restarting my computer. This can either not work or the project will be able to build/run again, but the errors return after a short amount of time
- Whitelisting the project folders and .dll files through my antivirus
- Completely turning off my antivirus protections while working on/running my project in Visual Studio
- Deleting the "obj" and "bin" folders from the project folders and Rebuilding. Sometimes this works and allows the project to run for a time, sometimes the errors re-appear immediately.
- Repairing Visual Studio 2022
- Uninstalling and Reinstalling Visual Studio 2022
- Using Process Explorer to see what programs are targeting the files. It says that nothing is using the files at that time
- Clearing out the cache based on this answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1221136/visual-studio-2022-clear-local-caches
- Moving the project to a different location. This will temporarily work, but the errors return
- Making a separate profile on my PC and running Visual Studio and my project there. Errors continue to appear.

My project repo is here: https://github.com/EddEnt/SocialHub . It is based on the Udemy course "Complete guide to building an app with .Net Core and React"

I don't know if there is an error in my code that is causing these errors to appear or not, but at this point I feel like I have tried and googled anything that I could find and it's causing me to lose focus on the issue. If any fix can be suggested that I haven't listed here, I'm more than open to attempting it.

Comment: Unable to write / unable to copy errors can mean instances of the process are still running even if no window is visible, check task manager.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to edit a solution into the question itself. If you've found that solution and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space provided below for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more details.

Comment: Figured out the issue. Webroot SecureAnywhere was interfering with running or building my project. Completely shutting Webroot down and relaunching Visual Studio fixed it. Rebuilding the project did not cause any error codes, where before it was, nor did launching the project. If anyone else has Webroot SecureAnywhere and is experiencing something similar, try developing with it off by right-clicking the Webroot icon under 'Show hidden icons', and selecting 'Shut down Protection'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the issue. Webroot SecureAnywhere was interfering with running or building my project. Completely shutting Webroot down and relaunching Visual Studio fixed it. Rebuilding the project did not cause any error codes, where before it was, nor did launching the project. If anyone else has Webroot SecureAnywhere and is experiencing something similar, try developing with it off by right-clicking the Webroot icon under 'Show hidden icons', and selecting 'Shut down Protection'.

Comment: Been dealing with this for weeks now. Just start out of the blue couple weeks back. Webroot must have auto-updated. Other than disabling it, did you figure out how to keep Webroot running but not kill all productivity?